# Failed to install some Extensions for vscode (not a DNS problem)

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code

I tried to install "Azure Resources" extension for vscode and gave me the message "Failed to install 'ms-azuretools.vscode-azureresourcegroups'".

I configured my network settings using the IP addresses 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 as DNS servers but it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: Please have a look at the error message in your screenshot. Do you have installed the latest version of VS Code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the latest version of VisualStudio Code(1.67.1) and then install the azure extension in VS code. So you dont get this error.

I have installed successfully, you can refer the below screenshot:

[image]